how to push boilerplate SAPUI5 project to the cloud foundry?
I followed this tutorial ( https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-blogs-by-members/project-shims-using-npm-modules-with-ui5/ba-p/13474992 ) and wanted to push it into the clound foundry on the SAP BTP and I only get the error not correctly uploaded / deployed.
Can anyone please tell me what I need to change / add ?
Thank you very much
